# how i can use hashSet in Theory inlinData

Tags: c#, xunit, theory, fact

I have a test class and I want write a test for one of my functions and I have to use HashSet in [Theory] inlineData but I can't use it.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new HashSet<string>() {"text1","text2"}, "str")]
public void BuildInvertedIndexTest(ISet<string> expectedDocContain, string searchingWord)
```

I wrote classData and memberData but It wasn't successful.
please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With  `MemberDataAttribute` the solution could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> BuildInvertedIndexTestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { new HashSet<string>() { "text1", "text2" }, "str" };
    yield return new object[] { ... };
}
```

The usage would look like this:

```
[Theory, MemberData(nameof(BuildInvertedIndexTestData))]
public void BuildInvertedIndexTest(ISet<string> expectedDocContain, string searchingWord)
```

---

I haven't tested this solution so it might happen that you need to change the `expectedDocContain` parameter's type to `HashSet<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `HashSet<T>` with `[InlineData]` as attributes only support simple types like `string`, `int`, `bool`, arrays etc.

You will need to use another way of parameterising the test, such as `[MemberData]` for `ISet<T>`/`HashSet<T>` which you can read more about in this blog post by Andrew Lock: https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/

Alternatively, you could use a `string[]` with `[InlineData]` and construct the `HashSet<string>` from that in the body of the test.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new string[] {"text1","text2"}, "six")]
public void BuildInvertedIndexTest(string[] expectedDocContain, string searchingWord)
{
    var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(expectedDocContain);
    // TODO Put the rest of your test here.
}
```